# Redirect spawned process to tempfile with the pid in its filename

Tags: process, mktemp

Suppose `myprogram` is spawned through the terminal (bash) and gets pid of 1234 (different everytime).

I want to redirect, both stdout and stderr, to a tempfile named `abc-$PID` (if the PID is 1234, use tempfile `abc-1234`.

The code looks like this now:

```
myprogram > /tmp/abc-$! 2>&1
```

it doesn't work

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in the shell, the redirection is parsed and handled before the command is run.  So the shell has no way of knowing what the child PID is at the time the `>` is parsed.

But we can cheat...  we know our own PID and we can `exec` the real program.  The `exec` avoids creating a new process ID, so the program executes with the same PID as we started with.

So for example:

```
$ cat  myprogram 
#!/bin/sh
echo hello.  I am $$
echo err >&2

$ cat wrapper 
#!/bin/sh

exec myprogram > foo-$$ 2>&1

$ ./wrapper 

$ ls
foo-10285  myprogram*  wrapper*

$ cat foo-10285 
hello. I am 10285
err
```